# Set checkmark in button on click

Tags: android, button

I have a button which when clicked shows a checkmark image just inside the right side of the button.
What's the best way to show this check mark?
I was hoping to just hide the image and when clicked display it, but I can't get it to display in the proper spot. I also saw android:drawableRight in the documentation, but is there a way to hide that until clicked?

xml for button and checkmark image

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"
    android:id="@+id/btn"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="24px"
    android:layout_width="24px"
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:src="@drawable/check_mark"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Thanks

Comment: So you're having trouble aligning it correctly, not hiding/displaying it via button click?

Comment: Yes, i can hide / unhide it fine, just can't get align it. I tried putting in a relative layout, but when i did that it shifted the button to the left of the screen, so i tried frame layout, but couldn't get it to the right spot / didn't know how to get it in the right spot. The button is of a set width (5/6th of the screen size) if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
Button btn = (Button)getViewById(R.id.btn);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chec_mark);

//hide drawable with this call
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null,null); //order of params (left, top, right, bottom)

//show drawable on right side of button with this call (in your onclick method)
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,drawable,null);
```